# ARM template for containers behind a load balancer

Tags: azure

I have an ARM template which creates a Load Balancer in front of a VM Scale Set. Is it possible to convert the VMSS resource to use container instances instead of VMs?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to convert VMSS into containers (its called virtual machine scale set for a reason). But you can run containers on top of VMSS, I'm not sure how viable is that thou.

Comment: Sure, yea I guess it makes sense that VMSS is made for VMs. Maybe I should make it clear that I am also open to suggestions where I can use something other than VMSS to replicate the same behaviour? Where instead of load balancing VMs, I would be load balancing containers.

Comment: take a look at azure container service